# Devise Registration Error - syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have just set up devise and am really struggling.

I've used almost no features this time around, as my earlier attempts, at integrating omniauth failed miserably. The only added extra is that I have required the admin to approve registrations.

I have links in my navbar which properly render simple forms for sign in and sign up.

When I attempt to complete the sign up form, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError at /users

syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

The only step I didn't follow in the setup was adding the notice and alert to my application layout. I deleted those messages because they add extra white space above my navbar when I run the file. I dont know why.

My home.html.erb is:

```
 <%= render "static/navigation" %>

<%= render "static/gollage" %>

<%= render "static/equation" %>
<%= render "static/infographic" %>


<%= render "static/ktocasestudy" %>

<%= render "static/educatorcomment" %>

<%= render "static/beta" %>


<%= render "static/footer" %>


  <script>
    $('#infographicacol').hover(
      function() {
        $('#popuphub').addClass( "active" );
      }, function() {
        $('#popuphub').removeClass( "active" );
      }
    );
    $('#infographicbcol').hover(
      function() {
        $('#popupmatch').addClass( "active" );
      }, function() {
        $('#popupmatch').removeClass( "active" );
      }
    );
    $('#infographicccol').hover(
      function() {
        $('#popuptool').addClass( "active" );
      }, function() {
        $('#popuptool').removeClass( "active" );
      }
    );
    $('#infographicdcol').hover(
      function() {
        $('#popupgallery').addClass( "active" );
      }, function() {
        $('#popupgallery').removeClass( "active" );
      }
    );
    </script>
```

My user/registration_controller has:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  #before_filter :check_permissions , :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ] 
  #skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication 
  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end 
end
```

and my user/profile_controller has:

```
   def index
     @users = User.all
   end




    # PATCH/PUT /users/1
      # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /users/1
      # DELETE /users/1.json
      def destroy
        @user.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to user_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_user
          @user = user.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
       def user_params
          params[:user].permit(:first_name, :last_name, :title, :country, :local_location )
        end
       end
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show your users controller and index.html.erb? It looks like you are missing a ] somewhere.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your help. I updated the question with those blocks of code. Thanks very much again.

Comment: In the referenced code, all instances of `[` are closed with the appropriate `]`. I suspect the problem will lie in one of your `render` files - do you have their code available for us?

Comment: Thank you both. I found one in my footer. Thank you both - I didn't think to check there. Cheers.